# How to access LoginView LoggedInTemplate's Control after user successfully logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I am trying to add href to hyperlink in Site.Master after user logs in to the website. The hyperlink is inside loggeintemplate. I have tried accessing it in OnLoggedIn event but its not rendered by then and is returned as null. Where could I access it?

Comment: have you tried to pass it as Session cookie?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it that way.

Comment: I think, that after the user successfully logs in (after the OnLoggedIn callback) there will be a page re-load. Maybe you can try it in the OnPreRender (or simply PreRender?). There you can also check if there is an authenticated user or not.

Comment: If url's value is being determined in OnLoggedIn event then how can I access it in master's page load event if I were to use session cookies.

Comment: @qqbenq: PreRender of which page? Because after user logs in a new page will be displayed based on the url determined. It could one of 5 possible pages.

Comment: But I guess the LoginView is in the master page, so I thought of the master's PreRender.

Comment: yes it is. So how do I get the value of url determined in log in page in master page?

Comment: I ended up using LoginView's pre-render event in Master page code.